# UFT 12.0 unable to synchronize an object using .Exists property

Tags: testing, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

from last few days i am trying to synchronize two objects that are dependent on each other for their execution.

EX: Object B should execute only after the completion of object A.

Now, in my scenario, the Object A is taking some time to execute, for this I need to synchronize the two objects.

The Completion of object will result in an image which will tell the user that the process is completed successfully or failed.

Below is my code:

```
sLoop = True

Do while sLoop

If (Browser("ABC").Page("PQR").Frame("XYZ").Image("BatchSuccess").Exist) then
    msgbox "in if"
    sLoop = false
Else
    msgbox "in else"
    sLoop = true
End If
Loop
```

Other Activities...

My IF condition is getting executed before it gets satisfied.
there is an image of ongoing process which the UFT is considering as the successful...

Note: there is also an image while executing the object. (observation, UFT is not able to distinguish between these 2 images)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **WaitProperty** method. **Exist** will return true when it finds Your object in app. 
For example

> objectA.WaitProperty(optionFromObjectSpy,someSpecificContent)

optionFromObjectSpy - innerhtml etc.

Comment: i have tried Wait property as below..

'code'
looping=TRUE
Do while looping
If Browser("ABC").Page("PQR").Frame("XYZ").Image("BatchSuccess").WaitProperty(nameProp,"BatchSuccess.gif") Then
 looping=FALSE
Else 
 looping=TRUE
End If
Loop
'code'code

but the loop is going infinite.. not entering in the If condition.

Comment: it should work if nameProp exist in Image attributes (in object spy)

Comment: code is as follow: 

`looping=TRUE 

Do while looping 
If Browser("ABC").Page("PQR").Frame("XYZ").Image("BatchSuccess").WaitProperty(nameP??rop,"BatchSuccess.gif") Then 
 looping=FALSE 
Else 
 looping=TRUE 
End If 

Loop`

it's not working.

Comment: This rather strange way of using loop ;)
Try this:
`Do
Loop While Browser("ABC").Page("PQR").Frame("XYZ").Image("BatchSuccess").WaitProperty(nameP‌​rop,"BatchSuccess.gif") = false`. I'm still not sure about nameProp. What exactly did you set to this variable? Maybe this property is not recognizable by QTP

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at your code and your question, one thing pops right into my head is that you can use wait time inside your exist statement.
Like :

```
If B().P().Image().Exist("10") Then  *'you can change the 10 second to anything you want*
    'Code here
End If
```

Or Alternatively you could create a function that will check if **readystate** of the browser (assuming its IE) is 4 or not.

```
do while ie.readystate <> 4
   Wait(1)
Loop
```

Call the function before doing anything with the Image object. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like -

```
While not Browser("ABC").Page("PQR").Frame("XYZ").Image("BatchSuccess").Exist
  Wait 1
  Browser("ABC").Sync
Wend
    'your code here after object A is synchronized 
     Browser("ABC").Page("PQR").Frame("XYZ").Image("BatchSuccess").Click
```